# Mysql 5.1.42 alter table auto_increment = 0 doesn't work, truncate does

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, truncate, alter-table

For my automated acceptance tests, I want inserts to start with id=1.
I achieved this on one PC (XP 32bit, mysql 5.1.something) with (after deleting all rows from the table), "alter table tableName auto_increment = 0".

I'm now setting up a new PC (Windows 7 64bit, mysql 5.1.42), and this command seems to have no effect.
I can see in the information_schema.tables table that the auto_increment value is not changed back to 0 --- it just keeps going up. If I try to change the value in that table directly, I'm told that access is denied to 'root'@'localhost'. Does this perhaps give a hint to my problem?

Other stackoverflow people had suggested that "truncate from tableName" is a good alternative. I'm happy to report that this works. But does anyone know why the "alter table" command won't reset the auto_increment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NOt sure why it worked on one server, and doesn't work on the other, but the [MySQL manual states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> To change the value of the
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT`  counter to be used
>   for new rows, do this:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
> ```
>
> **You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that
>   have already been used**.
>  For
>   MyISAM, if the value is less than or
>   equal to the maximum value currently
>   in the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the
>   value is reset to the current maximum
>   plus one.
>  For InnoDB, if the value
>   is less than the current maximum value
>   in the column, no error occurs and the
>   current sequence value is not changed.

Maybe that's the cause of the problem : you are trying to put the `auto_increment` counter back to 0, but it's already higher than that value -- and as you cannot reset it to a value that's less than any value that's already been used, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. It seems that my tables are using myISAM on this installation, rather than InnoDB which I'm more familiar with.

Comment: you need make table empty first, next reset . my pitfalls was I tried to reset first...